# Toggle iframe scrolling in javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll, scrollbar

How can I toggle an iframe's scrolling between on, off and auto in javascript? I tried changing the frame.scrolling attribute to "yes", "no" and "auto", but it doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the CSS attributes instead (overflow-x and overflow-y, or just overflow).

Link: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp