# repeatedly toggle iframe scrollbar in javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe, scrollbar

---

To ward off closing, yes I have looked at most of the related questions.
Here are some related questions that are not duplicates, but share the same title:
[scrollbar iframe in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104586/scrollbar-iframe-in-javascript) ,
[Toggle iframe scrolling in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715421/toggle-iframe-scrolling-in-javascript)
I am unable to make the solutions suggested there work. Now lets begin

---

hi, I need to toggle the scrollbar on an iframe as the content changes. I have some code that I thought would work, but it fails. All code below is from http://jsfiddle.net/3nnAf/2

To demo the concept, I'm trying to get an iframe scrollbar to turn on and off in a loop

Html:

> ```
>  <iframe src="www.google.com" id="Iframe" seamless scrolling="no" ></iframe>
> ```

Attempt using 'scrolling' attribute:

```
(function toggleIFrame(){
   var toggleScroll = document.getElementById('Iframe').scrolling == 'no';
   if (toggleScroll){
      document.getElementById('Iframe').scrolling = 'yes';
   }else{
      document.getElementById('Iframe').scrolling = 'no';
   }
   setTimeout(toggleIFrame, 2000);
 }());
```

Attempt using styling

```
(function toggleIFrame(){
 var toggleScroll = document.getElementById('Iframe').style.overflowY == 'scroll';
 if (toggleScroll){
    document.getElementById('Iframe').style.overflowY = 'hidden';
 }else{
    document.getElementById('Iframe').style.overflowY = 'scroll';
 } 
 setTimeout(toggleIFrame, 2000);
}());
```

Is it possible to turn the iframe scoll bars on and off repeatedly?

Thanks,
User117...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortounately, I was unable to repeatedly toggle the iframe scroll bars, so I

- expanded the iframe expand to fit all the content inside
- added a div wrapper to which I could add and remove scrollbars

The finished code was as follows...

HTML

```
<div id="IframeWrapper">
   <iframe src="www.google.com" id="Iframe" seamless scrolling="no" ></iframe>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
(function toggleIFrame(){  

autoResizeIFrame('Iframe');
var toggleScroll = $('#IframeWrapper').hasClass('showBars');

$('#IframeWrapper').removeClass('hideBars');
$('#IframeWrapper').removeClass('showBars');

if (toggleScroll){
        $('#IframeWrapper').addClass('hideBars');
}else{
        $('#IframeWrapper').addClass('showBars');
} 

window.setTimeout(toggleIFrame, 2000);
}());

function autoResizeIFrame(id){
var newheight;
var newwidth;

if(document.getElementById){
   newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollHeight;
   newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document .body.scrollWidth;
}

  document.getElementById(id).style.height= (newheight) + "px";
  document.getElementById(id).style.width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
```

CSS

```
#IframeWrapper {width:300px; height:300px;}
#IframeWrapper.hideBars {overflow:hidden;}
#IframeWrapper.showBars {overflow:scroll;}
```

See it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/3nnAf/5/

References: Ahmy's answer at [Adjust width height of iframe to fit with content in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
 <iframe src="www.google.com" id="Iframe" seamless scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents you from interacting with a page from another domain.

**EDIT**

Ohh.. I'm bad, I'm bad.

```
setTimeOut(toggleIFrame(), 2000);
```

The function is called:

[window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

(Your error console would have told you that, BTW.)

**EDIT 2**
Ok, I actually did run the code and make some changes to it.

You had three major issues that kept the code from running propertly.

1. On Chrome, at least, the Same Origin Policy kept Google from even loading in an iFrame.  Thus, nothing ran.
2. You did have the wrong method of `setTimeOut` over `setTimeout`.  I see you fixed this in your edit.
3. You were using `toggleIFrame()` in your `setTimeout` invocation.  I see you've caught this one too.

This code does correctly toggle the overflowY between `'hidden'` and `''`

```
(function toggleIFrame2(){
    var iFrame = document.getElementById('Iframe');
    console.log("Starting value" + iFrame.style.overflowY );
    var oldValue =  iFrame.style.overflowY;

    function inner() {
        var toggleScroll = (iFrame.style.overflowY === 'hidden');

        var newValue = toggleScroll ?  oldValue : 'hidden'

        console.log(newValue);
        iFrame.style.overflowY = newValue;

        setTimeout(inner, 2000);
    }
    inner();
}());
```

At this point, newValue is correctly being toggled -- but that isn't yielding the desired effect.  I'll admit to that.

With the major show stoppers in your code resolved, perhaps one of the answers on toggling scroll bars will work for you now.

Comment: but I'm changing the scrolling on the iframe, not on the content inside?

Comment: if I remove the set timeout part it works okay, but the recursive looping and or toggle and retoggle part seems to mess it up.

Comment: This may come across as harsh, but please attempt to run your answer before posting it.

Comment: @user1778606 -- If I was getting *paid* to answer, sure I would.  Heck, at work I'll take a full half-hour to write up a test conditions for my answers.  Considering that I'm answering questions here *for free* in my spare time -- deal with it.  I'm right, at a glance, far more often than I'm wrong.  That's why you've got the option of down-voting me.

Comment: thanks for the attempt. I don't like to downvote, but I don't like meh answers b/c people are far more likey to skip over the question if it has an answer (even if the answer is "Monkeys")